# resources.getIdentifier() returns 0 always for release apk

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable

I have method for get resource id from drawable it's working fine with debug apk but not working with release apk.

FYI : drwables are loaded from nodpi

```
fun String.getDrawableId(c: Context): Int {
    try {
        return c.resources.getIdentifier(
            this.replace(".jpg", "").replace(".png", "").replace(".wepb", ""),
            "drawable",
            c.packageName
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return -1
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I did nor=t get any error or exception

Comment: Have you tried hard coding the package name and see what happens?

Comment: Obfuscating your code and resource names get mangled too?

Comment: @GiddyNaya yes I tried but it's not working for me. in debug it's working fine

Comment: @laalto resources was jpeg and png(from local json) that's why I used replace.

Comment: Yes, obfuscation (r8, proguard or something) might touch the generated `R` but not your json.

Comment: how can I fix this issue?